# Induced map on cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $M= \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C} \times \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C} \times \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}= S^2 \times S^2 \times S^2$, and let $D$ be the subvariety of $M$ defined by the equation
$$
t_0t_1t_2 = s_0s_1s_2,
$$
where $(t_0,s_0),(t_1,s_1),(t_2,s_2)$ are homogeneous coordinates on $M$. Then $D$ is an algebraic surface, or a $4$-dimensional submanifold of the six-dimensional real manifold $M$.

The the inclusion $j:D \hookrightarrow M$ induces a map on the singular cohomology groups (use whatever cohomology theory you like; singular cohomology, deRham,...)
$$
H^4(M) \to H^4(D).
$$
I want to know what this map is. In fact, it suffices to know of it is zero/non-zero.

By Künneth (etc.) I know that $H^4(M)=\mathbb Z^3$ and $H^4(M)=\mathbb Z$.

--

I would be happy for any hints/suggestions for how to solve this.

Comment: Since $H^4$ of $M$ is generated by products of elements in $H^1$ and the map is a morphism of algebras, I would start with trying to see what happens in degree $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This should really be a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet.)

The generators of $H^4$ can be thought of (via Poincare duality) as codimension-2 cycles, i.e. curves on $M$. In this description, pullback corresponds to intersection with $D$. From this you can see that the map is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to look at the details of this: intersecting with $D$ gives a union of three disjoint $\mathbb P^1$s. How can I think of these as a class in $H^4(D)$?

Comment: @FredrikMeyer: the generators of $H^4(X)$ are of the form $\{pt\} \times \{pt\} \mathbf P^1$ (and permutations). Intersecting these with $D$ gives a *point* in each case.